# No output with .duplicated in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to find all of the rows which have duplicates in the columns of city, round_latitude, and round_longitude. So, if two rows share the same values in each of those columns, it would be returned.

I'm not exactly sure what is going on here: I'm certain that there are duplicates in the dataset. No error is returned when running In[38], the column names are returned but there are no entries. What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix this?

If it helps, I'm also working off of some of the code in [this guide.](http://datadryad.org/bitstream/handle/10255/dryad.114711/Sci-Hub.html?sequence=2) (The format is HTML.)

```
# In[29]:

def dl_by_loc(path):
    endname = "USA_downloads.csv"
    with open(path + endname, "r") as f:
        data = pd.read_csv(f)
        data.columns = ["date","city","coords","doi","latitude","longitude","round_latitude","round_longitude"]
        data = data.groupby(["round_latitude","round_longitude","city"]).count()
        data = data.rename(columns = {"date":"downloads"})
        return data["downloads"]


# In[30]:

downloads_by_coords = dl_by_loc(path)
len(downloads_by_coords)


# In[31]:

downloads_by_coords = downloads_by_coords.reset_index()
downloads_by_coords.columns = ["round_latitude","round_longitude","city","downloads"]


# In[32]:

downloads_by_coords.head()


# In[38]:

by_coords = downloads_by_coords.reset_index()
coord_dupes = by_coords[by_coords.duplicated(subset=["round_latitude","round_longitude","city"])]
coord_dupes
```

Here are a few lines from the data, as requested:

```
2016-02-16 00:32:19,Philadelphia,"39.9525839,-75.1652215",10.1042/BJ20091140,39.9525839,-75.1652215,40.0,-75.0
2016-02-16 00:32:19,Philadelphia,"39.9525839,-75.1652215",10.1096/fj.05-5309fje,39.9525839,-75.1652215,40.0,-75.0
2016-02-16 00:32:19,Philadelphia,"39.9525839,-75.1652215",10.1186/1478-811X-11-15,39.9525839,-75.1652215,40.0,-75.0
2016-02-16 00:32:21,Houston,"29.7604267,-95.3698028",10.1039/P19730002379,29.7604267,-95.36980279999999,30.0,-95.0
```

Comment: @ayhan The question has been updated with lines from that file.

Comment: @ayhan, why did you delete your answer? It perfectly answered this question...

Comment: @MaxU Is there any way to undelete it? That post was very helpful, I was just busy and couldn't work on the issue yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

`dl_by_loc(path)` returns a Series with a MultiIndex:

```
round_latitude  round_longitude  city        
30.0            -95.0            Houston         1
40.0            -75.0            Philadelphia    3
Name: downloads, dtype: int64
```

If you take a look at the definition of that function, it groups the DataFrame by round_latitude, round_longitude and city columns and counts the number of occurrences. Later on, you convert this to a DataFrame by calling reset_index(). Now, the downloads column is showing how many times each lat, lon, city combination occurred in the original DataFrame. Since it is a groupby result, these combinations are in fact not duplicated because they were aggregated previously. If you want to detect duplicated ones from this DataFrame, you can use:

```
by_coords[by_coords['downloads']>1]
```

Your method would still work in the original DataFrame. Note that removing duplicates or grouping data with float type data has some [risks](http://floating-point-gui.de/). Pandas generally handles them but to make sure, if you want 1-digit precision, you can multiply by 10 and convert to integer.