# Check if value is in categorical series of float range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories

I got the following pandas DataFrame :

```
     bucket             value
0   (15016, 18003.2]    368
1   (12028.8, 15016]    132
2   (18003.2, 20990.4]  131
3   (9041.6, 12028.8]   116
4   (50.128, 3067.2]    82
5   (3067.2, 6054.4]    79
6   (6054.4, 9041.6]    54
7   (20990.4, 23977.6]  28
8   (23977.6, 26964.8]  8
9   (26964.8, 29952]    2
```

`buckets` have been computed with `pd.cut()` command (dtype is `cateogry`)

I would like to check if a value, let's say `my_value = 20000`, is in one of `bucket`'s range.

It could return a dataframe with one more column :

```
     bucket             value   value_in_bucket
0   (15016, 18003.2]    368     FALSE
1   (12028.8, 15016]    132     FALSE
2   (18003.2, 20990.4]  131     TRUE
3   (9041.6, 12028.8]   116     FALSE
4   (50.128, 3067.2]    82      FALSE
5   (3067.2, 6054.4]    79      FALSE
6   (6054.4, 9041.6]    54      FALSE
7   (20990.4, 23977.6]  28      FALSE
8   (23977.6, 26964.8]  8       FALSE
9   (26964.8, 29952]    2       FALSE
```

The main problem is that each item of `bucket` is a string, so I could split the string into 2 columns and use a basic test and an `apply` but it does not seem so classy to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can apply `pd.cut()` **using the same bins** (or, better, as [@ayhan suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850859/check-if-value-is-in-categorical-series-of-float-range/38851020?noredirect=1#comment65066380_38851020) save bins when you create `bucket` column, using `retbins=True` parameter) on `value` column and compare it to the `bucket` column.

Demo:

```
In [265]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,20, 5), columns=list('a'))

In [266]: df
Out[266]:
    a
0   9
1   6
2  13
3  11
4  17
```

create `bucket` column and save bins in one step:

```
In [267]: df['bucket'], bins = pd.cut(df.a, bins=5, retbins=True)

In [268]: df
Out[268]:
    a        bucket
0   9   (8.2, 10.4]
1   6  (5.989, 8.2]
2  13  (12.6, 14.8]
3  11  (10.4, 12.6]
4  17    (14.8, 17]

In [269]: bins
Out[269]: array([  5.989,   8.2  ,  10.4  ,  12.6  ,  14.8  ,  17.   ])
```

generate a new column which we want to compare:

```
In [270]: df['b'] = np.random.randint(10,12, 5)

In [271]: df
Out[271]:
    a        bucket   b
0   9   (8.2, 10.4]  10
1   6  (5.989, 8.2]  11
2  13  (12.6, 14.8]  11
3  11  (10.4, 12.6]  11
4  17    (14.8, 17]  11
```

compare whether we have matches (using saved `bins`):

```
In [272]: pd.cut(df.b, bins=bins) == df.bucket
Out[272]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: You can also pass `retbins=True` to the first cut, and use that in the second cut. This will also work for a single value (`pd.cut([2000], bins)` returns the category for value 2000).

Comment: @ayhan, it's a very good point, thank you! I'll add it to the answer...

Comment: Worked like a charm with both of your answers, thank you.

Comment: @ayhan, btw, can you undelete [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38819324/5741205)? I think it perfectly answers that question? OP wanted to see your answer as well...

Comment: @MaxU Ok I did. The OP asked another question with a similar dataset so I thought the problem was something else.